# How to properly use the range() function to print/iterate a grid

Tags: python-3.x

If I have a list/grid:

grid = [

```
    ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], #[0,0]-[0,5]
    ['.', '0', '0', '.', '.', '.'], #[1,0]-[1,5]
    ['0', '0', '0', '0', '.', '.'], #[2,0]-[2,5]
    ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '.'], #[3,0]-[3,5]
    ['.', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], #[4,0]-[4,5]
    ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '.'], #[5,0]-[5,5]
    ['0', '0', '0', '0', '.', '.'], #[6,0]-[6,5]
    ['.', '0', '0', '.', '.', '.'], #[7,0]-[7,5]
    ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']] #[8,0]-[8,5]
```

What would be the best method to step through this grid and print out the contents, would it be `range()`?

something like:

```
def print_grid(grid):
```

I see a lot of this `for i in range()`- what is the 'i' when it is never declared or is it a type of counter? I'm very new to python so excuse any confusion. Would I use a nested for loop to step through the cords of the grid?

Comment: Alternatively you can do something like: >>> for i in grid:
...     for j in i:
...             print(j)

Comment: So 'j' is a variable for the character within 'i' which is the grid?

Comment: 'i' is basically representing the coordinates of the grid?

Comment: Oh yes. I do this when i have to deal with some matrix.

Comment: Do you know how I'd print each element from the grid instead? I need to print out the elements from [0.0]-[0,5] and then make a new line for the next elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for i in range(limit)` creates a list of numbers from 0 to `limit`, and goes through each item in `limit` and sets `i` to that item. However, for going through and printing a grid, using `range()` isn't the best method.

```
for row in grid:
    for item in row:
        print(item, end = " ")
    print()
```

`for row in grid` goes through each list in `grid`, and sets `row` to that list. `for item in row` goes through each item in `row` and sets `item` to that item. `print(item, end = " ")` `print`s `item` out, and `end = " "` makes it so that instead of a *newline* being added after `print`, it adds a *space*. The empty `print` command after the inner for loop inserts a new line for the next row to be printed on.

Hope this clarifies your confusion